# Does Pycharm have Docstring Conventions checks (PEP 257)?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new using Pycharm and I was not able to find anything that refers to PEP 257 checks in code. I have been using Atom with its specific packages to work with Python and it has managed PEP 257 checks very well. Because of that I would be surprised if a non cheap IDE did not have this feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked through the PyCharm plugins repository and settings and it seems, that it doesn't yet check PEP 257, nor adequate plugin exists. Currently, only PEP 8 is checked.

You can check what is inspected in `Settings>Editor>Inspections`

**Edit:**
I found this functionality has been requested already on May 2014, so I believe it won't be long now.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-12553

Comment: Note that this was not requested on May 2017, it was requested on Mar 2014. PyCharm developers definitely listen to their community, and if this is something which is important to "you" (whoever is reading this), I encourage you to vote for it. In the last 3 years, only 4 people have voted for it so I would agree that it would be low priority.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the date. And you are, of course right - more votes = higher priority

Answer (score 5):

As noted above, PEP257 is not implemented in PyCharm. If it's important to you, I suggest voting for it in the link @Michal found. PyCharm developers definitely listen to the community. 4 people voting for it in 3 years doesn't really put it as high priority though.

However, if you want to be able to call this from within PyCharm, you could install [pydocstyle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydocstyle), and call it from inside of PyCharm using `Settings | Tools | External Tools`. This wont give you things highlighted as warnings, but will give you the check you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not having PEP 257 checks yet.
Well have a free recommendation for you, use Sublime Text 3 and and its plugins for Python development. It is free, fast and awesome.

Comment: FYI Sublime Text is not free, but does have an evaluation version.